# sort the fitness function array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am using genetic algorithms to evolve something and I have a double Array as shown below.

```
fitness[0] = 15.0
fitness[1] = 12.0 
fitness[2] = 13.0
fitness[3] = 17.0 
fitness[4] = 8.0
fitness[5] = 18.0
```

Array Index represents **Population** and it's value is **fitness** function. 
I can sort the Array easily, by using a sorting Algorithm or can use some thing like below -

```
Integer[] arr =
    { 12, 67, 1, 34, 9, 78, 6, 31 };
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer x, Integer y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("low to high:" + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

But I want to know the indexes after sorting, as shown below: -

```
fitness[5] = 18.0 
fitness[3] = 17.0  
fitness[0] = 15.0
fitness[2] = 13.0
fitness[1] = 12.0 
fitness[4] = 8.0
```

Basically I want the output like 5, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4. Which means 5th person is good than 3rd so on..

I wrote a code with too many if-else, and it some what worked for me. But the code looks ugly and confusing. 
If I try to load the data/copy to HASH SET, but the values on the RHS may be repeated.

Is there any better way for me than using lot's of if-else statements?

Comment: Nothing difficult here. Convert it to an array of two columns and sort all rows by the 1st column. At the most you will need a custom Comporator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way of solving this problem is to sort a permutation array, like this:

```
final Integer[] arr =
{ 12, 67, 1, 34, 9, 78, 6, 31 };
final Integer[] perm = new Integer[arr.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != perm.length ; i++) {
    perm[i] = i;
}
Arrays.sort(perm, new Comparator<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y)
    {
        return arr[x] - arr[y];
    }
});

System.out.println("low to high:" + Arrays.toString(perm));
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/q69UnI)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I tried to convert your code to accept double Array instead of INT and it's not giving the correct output. Can you please help me what am I doing wrong here? [Posted my Double Array code below as another Answer)

Comment: @RealCoder Replace subtraction with a call of Double.compare(arr[x], arr[y])

Answer (score 0):

```
final double[] fitnessArray = new double [6];


        fitnessArray[0] = 15.0;
        fitnessArray[1] = 12.0;
        fitnessArray[2] = 13.0;
        fitnessArray[3] = 17.0;
        fitnessArray[4] = 8.0;
        fitnessArray[5] = 18.0;

        //Find the Fittest Attack BOT

        Double[] perm = new Double[fitnessArray.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i != perm.length ; i++) {
            perm[i] = (double) i;
        }
        Arrays.sort(perm, new Comparator<Double>()
                {
            @Override
            public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (int) (fitnessArray[o1.intValue()] - fitnessArray[o1.intValue()]); // Higher value first
            }
                });

        System.out.println("low to high:" + Arrays.toString(perm));
```